# Long-standing effort?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality-in-context, word-in-context

Does long-standing sound right to native speakers in this context? Example: *Your long-standing effort has paid off.*
Does this sound idiomatic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the fact that I would *personally* use *long-lasting efforts*, replacing *standing* with *lasting* and making it plural, I checked something objective and queried Google Books Ngram Viewer.

[According to it](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=long-standing%20effort%2C%20long-standing%20efforts%2C%20long-lasting%20effort%2C%20long-lasting%20efforts&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clong%20-%20standing%20effort%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clong%20-%20standing%20efforts%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clong%20-%20lasting%20effort%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clong%20-%20lasting%20efforts%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Clong%20-%20standing%20effort%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clong%20-%20standing%20efforts%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clong%20-%20lasting%20effort%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clong%20-%20lasting%20efforts%3B%2Cc0), while the plural form is the more common, so, too, is *long-standing*, at least in printed form.

[image: long-standing efforts]

Per this, your use of *long-standing effort* (or *long-standing efforts*) is just fine.